# Express + CloudFlare with SSL

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, cloudflare

I have an express app freshly created using `express appName`.
I've changed the port to 443.
The domain is under CloudFlare's proxy with SSL enabled.
When I go to the website though, I get the CloudFlare page `Web server is down` instead of seeing the express index page.

How can I make Express work with CloudFlare's SSL?

Comment: Got it -- need to create https server. (https.createServer and not http.createServer). Giving it self-signed certs (which allows me to use Full SSL on CloudFlare's pro plan as well).

Comment: Good work. Can you post this as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options:

- You need to alter your app such that it is able to accept HTTPS connections instead of HTTP. You can do this by using the [HTTPS library](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) instead of HTTP.
- You can switch to Flexible SSL instead of Full, but this is not recommended for a lot of applications as it means the connection from Cloudflare's Edge to your Origin is unencrypted.